# Sometimes Python code stops and starts only when pressed CTRL+C in CMD

Tags: python

I have a script that runs 24/7. It uploads file to the server for 5 hours, and do `time.sleep(68400)`. But sometimes, It just stops in between, and When I press CTRL+C, it starts running again.

This happens to many of my scripts on many of my computers. So I don't think code is necessary.

Does anyone know, why this happens or a fix?

Comment: not sure about the use case, but running a script and then sleeping for 19 hours? Any reason for not using scheduler like cron?

Comment: Then I need to add a checkpoint file also, I think. To save the process I made, and start from there. No other specific reason. Is it a problem?

Comment: Are you calling your code from command prompt or a bash script?

Comment: Command Prompt Like `python scriptname.py`

Comment: i would use a real scheduler like https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html when you want to use python for everything, "Task Scheduler" on windows or cron on linux

Comment: This also happen to my other script, that run 24/7...without any sleep. I am looking for root cause.